# SetActive() in unity

Tags: c#, variables, object, unity-game-engine

I've just seen an alert in Unity3D that says using

`this.gameObject.active = BackdropVisible;`

is obsolete.

- warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.GameObject.active' is obsolete:
- `GameObject.active is obsolete.
- Use GameObject.SetActive(), GameObject.activeSelf or GameObject.activeInHierarchy.'

I only wrote it yesterday but clearly it's old news now ;)

However, setting

`this.gameObject.SetActive(true);`

works fine; but

`this.GameObject.SetActive(true);`

doesn't. The difference being the capital "G" - as used in the error message

Can anyone clear up the confusion? (I only just started c# yesterday) I'm guessing the lower case version is a variable and the one in the documentation is an object; but to untrained eyes they are the same thing. Clearly they are not.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GameObject` with capital G is a **class type**, and produce a compiler error since makes no sense in that context.

`this.gameObject` is a **member field** of `MonoBehaviors` referencing the `GameObject` instance of the GO the script is attached to.

Comment: Thanks - that's much better than looking at the docs which always read like stereo instructions.